# Getting warning from Cassandra Java driver, contact point "wasn't found in the control host's system.peers at startup"

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I notice the below WARN log message from datastax cassandra java driver. Please help in understanding this message. How crucial is it ? What is it's impact ? How to fix it.

> Cassandra Version : 2.1.8
>
> Datastax Java Driver : 3.1.0
>
> WARN   2017-02-23 14:54:53,926
>   com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster:localhost-startStop-1 - You listed
>   nosql.campany.com/192.168.89.184:9042 in your contact points, but it
>   wasn't found in the control host's system.peers at startup

Comment: can you include the output from `nodetool status` ? How many nodes?

Comment: it's a single node cluster in out test environment.

Comment: @VinodJayachandran did you resolve your issue? I'm facing the same thing here

Answer (score 2):

First check your system.peers table. You should not see any rows in your case.

Probably your hostname is getting resolves to multiple IP address.  Please use ip address(instead of localhost) in your cassandra.yaml file.

Check this link:
https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/pull/340